# Where does a modular tensor category come from?

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory

I have studied the definition of a modular tensor category.

I jumped into this subject and almost have no background. My question is: what kind of mathematics does a modular tensor category generalize?

I read somewhere that some representation theory is related to it. But I don't know the detail. (nor I don't know much about the representation theory.)

What is the motivation to define such an abstract notion?

Comment: A reference is Bakalov & Kirillov, Lectures on tensor categories and modular functors.

Answer (score 1):

Modular tensor categories describe the structure that an extended 3-dimensional [topological field theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_field_theory) (with a particular choice of target category) assigns to a circle.

An important class of examples of such a theory are the [Chern-Simons theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Simons_theory), which depend on a choice of compact simple connected simply connected (at least this is the easiest case) Lie group $G$ and an integer $k$. The corresponding modular tensor category admits two equivalent descriptions, one in terms of the representation theory of the quantum group $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ and one in terms of the representation theory of the loop group $LG$. In fact it is standard to construct Chern-Simons by constructing these modular tensor categories and then applying the [Reshetikhin-Turaev construction](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Reshetikhin-Turaev+construction).